# Angular circular dependency fix with forwardref

Tags: angularjs, angular, circular-dependency

I've got a Problem.

We are running good with Unit Tests in our Project but now we found a circular dependency and no we cant change it that easy.

So I created a little project to see how we could fix this or workaround.

So now I devided to try it with forwardref because it seems like the best solution but I can't really guess what the problem is that it won't work.

If you understood this or not here is the project: https://gitlab.com/Nter/forward-app/

We really need to fix this so if you could help me it would be awesome.

Comment: You haven't clearly explained the problem, you need to be more descriptive. Are you encountering an error? If so, you should post it. How do you know you have a circular dependency? Why can you not change it? I don't really want to install a repo to try to help with a very ambiguous problem.

Comment: I quickly looked at your code, and I'd say your time service should not be importing your weather service, since that's clearly not it's responsibility. The time service should only deal with time and should not import anything.

Comment: I made this Project to simulate a circular dependency. And yes I get a error: Can't resolve all parameters for TimeService